# How do I display the full content of LOB column in Oracle SQL*Plus?

Tags: oracle, blob, sqlplus, clob, lob

When I try to display the contents of a LOB (large object) column in SQL*Plus, it is truncated.  How do I display the whole thing?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
SQL> set long 30000
SQL> show long
long 30000
```

Comment: This with Kevin's answer is what I actually needed.

Comment: @KapilVyas You can add the command to your login.sql if you want it to be executed automatically. On Unix systems, that file should be placed in your home directory.

Answer (score 20):

You may also need:

```
SQL> set longchunksize 30000
```

Otherwise the LOB/CLOB will wrap.