# Sql not generating the fulltext when queried

Tags: sql, oracle

Right now i'm just playing around with the cursor_sharing parameter. The query I ran that is giving me trouble is this right here

```
select sql_fulltext from v$sql where sql_fulltext like '%select * from systest%';
```

This is the Output:

```
select sql_id,sql_fulltext,loaded_versions,executions from v$sql where sql_fullt
```

But, the full text that is suppose to show up is

```
select sql_id,sql_fulltext,loaded_versions,executions from v$sql where sql_fulltext like '%select * from systest%';
```

Anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

You did not tell which client you are using, so I assume it's SQL*PLUS.

the column sql_fulltext of view v$sql is of type CLOB. CLOBs can get very big, so clients might truncate them by default. 
There is a question already: [How do I display the full content of LOB column in Oracle SQL*Plus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122772/how-do-i-display-the-full-content-of-lob-column-in-oracle-sqlplus) - If you are using other clients, you might still get an idea how to get the full CLOB.