# How to see the whole content of a varchar2 column in oracle sqlplus terminal?

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, docker, sqlplus

I am trying to inspect a database content inside an `Oracle XE` from a `Docker POD`, but when I create a query string I get only the first 80 characters from each text column. How could I get the entire content using only the `sqlplus` terminal, NOT the `SQL Developer`? I tried to use `spool` command to send it to a file, but it comes with the same limitation.

*Note: THIS EXALMPLE IMAGE MENTIONS `CLOB` BUT THE COLUMN IS A `VARCHAR2`, SORRY !*

[image]

Comment: Please, check the reference for [`COL[UMN] <colname> FOR[MAT] A<number of chars>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/COLUMN.html#GUID-643B665F-B134-4A0B-88F7-10400D6D199E) command

Comment: Your example code is showing a `clob`, not a `varchar2`. See if [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122772/how-do-i-display-the-full-content-of-lob-column-in-oracle-sqlplus) helps.

Comment: Note that if your column is `clob` (as has been pointed out already), the SQL\*Plus command `COLUMN ....` will not help; that is only for `varchar2` columns. To control how much of a `clob` is shown, you need to use a different command: `set long [n]` where `n` is the number of characters to show. You can set it to 1000, or whatever you need. Note that the default (which you can see if you run `show long` in the SQL\*Plus terminal) is 80, explaining what you noticed.

Comment: Oh, no, it's not `CLOB` it's just the last thing that I saw in a forum, so I tried, but nothing. This is actually a `VARCHAR2` column, sorry!

Comment: If your actual problem has to do with a `clob`, could you update the question so that your example isn't using a `clob`?  `SQL*Plus` deals with the two data types pretty differently so I'm not sure what your real problem is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I display the full content of LOB column in Oracle SQL\*Plus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122772/how-do-i-display-the-full-content-of-lob-column-in-oracle-sqlplus)

Comment: Perhaps part of the confusion is that SQL\*Plus cares about the type of the *expression*, which is not necessarily the same as the original *column*. While your column may be a VARCHAR2, the `TO_CLOB` function converts the value into a CLOB, so the CLOB rules apply here.